# "Too Many Values" When Selecting Multiple Values For An In Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WHERE year in (
   CASE WHEN expression
   THEN (select yearOne, yearOne - 1 from table)
   ELSE (select yearOne from table)
   END
)
```

For example, assume the yearOne value = 2023.

If the expression is true I want the were clause to be:

`WHERE year in (2023, 2022)`

Otherwise if the expression is false, just use 2023

`ELSE WHERE year in (2023)`

Expecting the case statement to return multiple values to use with an in statement.

Comment: **1.** A `CASE` expression returns exactly one value, so it is not appropriate here. **2.** A `CASE` expression is used to apply boolean expressions (e.g. in `SELECT` or `ORDER BY`). The `WHERE` clause already is a boolean expression. You don't need `CASE` expressions inside it hence. Simply use boolean operators (`AND` and `OR`) there to express in which case you want to select a row.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thomething like that ?

```
WHERE (
  (expression AND year IN (
    (select yearOne from table),
    (select yearOne-1 from table)
   ))
   OR (NOT expression AND year IN (select yearOne from table))
)
```

Comment: probably won't perform well .. at least split it up:
where year in ( select yearOne from table )
 or ( year in ( select yearOne-1 from table) and expression )
since the "yearOne" is wanted always, don't need any extra condition with it ;)

Comment: Or common table expression ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a complete sample, so understanding what you're working with is impossible .

for example, how many records are in "table" and what do they look like ?

Assuming, for the moment, that "table" has only 1 record in it (based on the way  you're writing this query) .. this would generate what you're trying for .. but it's likely not the "best" solution .. Especially if "table" has >1 row!!

```
WHERE year in ( select yearOne from table union all
            select yearOne - 1 from table where expression
          )
```

The reason you're getting the error you are, is your case is returning inconsistent results (2 cols in first clause, 1 in 2nd).
You're trying to generate results to look like the typical list you see with in:
ie  IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4)

However, when it comes down to it, Oracle treats this more like it's own data set (ie 4 rows from a table with one col, with rows (1, 2, 3, 4) )

So using :  IN ( select col from table)   that returns 4 rows (1,2,3,4) would work - and this is the principle I'm using in above .. since you seem to want two results only:

```
IN ( 2023, 2022 )
or
IN ( 2023 )
```

I used a query, using union all to generate the 2nd row .. but have a WHERE condition on that 2nd row to limit it to your (expression) condition

If you can provide a full working example, with expected results ... we can get a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because your `CASE` statement is producing inconsistent results.  It is because your `CASE` statement is designed to produce multiple results, which is not possible.  A `CASE` statement must return a single result.

You could try:

```
WHERE year in (
  select distinct yearOne - 1
  from "table"
  where <expression>
  union
  select distinct yearOne
  from "table"
)
```

It may be clearer or more efficient to design your `FROM` clause to define this as an `INNER JOIN`.

```
FROM "table2" t
  INNER JOIN "table" tPreviousYear on tPreviousYear.yearOne - 1 = t.year
                                  and <expression>
  INNER JOIN "table" tYear on tYear.yearOne = t.year
```

A better understanding of your database structure would be helpful.